# Angular chartjs directive

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I want to use this angularJS directive for chartjs
http://earlonrails.github.io/angular-chartjs-directive/

The only issue is that it uses the HTML5 element chart:

```
 <chart value="myChart"></chart>
```

Is it possible to convert this to a directive and use it as follows? So instead of a  object, we use it as an attribute of a div.

```
<div chart-use="myChart" />
```

Update:

I revised the code on chart-js directive as follows:

```
angular.module('chartjs-directive', []).
directive('div-chart', function () {
var baseWidth = 600;
var baseHeight = 400;

return {
  restrict: 'A',
  template: '<canvas></canvas>',
  scope: {
    //chartObject: "=value"
  },
 ..............
 ............
    });
```

and UI like this:

```
  <!--<chart value="myChart" id="myCoolChart"></chart>-->
  <div id="myColChart" div-chart></div>
```

But this is not working. I assume it's because of this:

```
 $scope.myChart.data = data;
```

But I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way to do it.

```
angular.module('chartjs-directive', []).
 directive('divChart', function () {
var baseWidth = 600;
var baseHeight = 400;

return {
  restrict: 'A',
  template: '<canvas></canvas>',
  scope: {
    divChart:"=",
    chartObject: "=value"
  },
------
------
});
```

In HTML:

```
 <div id="myColChart" div-Chart value="myChart"></div>
```

I know this is basic stuff, but this is the first time I'm working with angular.

Comment: Hello, i am new to anjular js.. i have generated charts using JavaScript.. can you give the complete code in anjular js..

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to change directive name and its restrict value.

Your chart directive should look like this:

```
 app.directive('chartUse', function () {

    return {
       restrict: "A",
       .....
    }
 });
```

Comment: You should avoid to use the `ng` prefix on custom directive. [See the best practices](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Best-Practices)

Comment: If I don't use ng prefix, I could still create it as app.directive('datachart', function()..... right? So I can bind it like <div data-chart="mychart">

Comment: Slightly modified my question.